# Attempt to remove files that only contain one line of content using Powershell; Getting null Path error

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a large accumulation of files in a test environment, the majority of which contain only a header row, and thus no useful information. They consume analysis resource when we want to find the useful data, so I want to delete them.

I have worked out how to identify the filenames, but when I then apply the Remove-Item commandlet, the following happens:

- The files that do have only one line are indeed deleted
- But, the filenames that should be skipped generate the following error:

```
 Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
 null. At line:3 char:44
 +   where-object { $_.lines -eq 1 }).Name  | remove-item -whatif  )
 +                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Here is the Powershell command that I have concocted..

```
gci *20210114*X0000002015*CDR.csv -file | % {
   (($_ | select-object -property 'Name', @{ label = 'lines'; expression = { (gc $_ | measure-object -line).lines  } } |
   where-object { $_.lines -eq 1 }).Name  | remove-item -whatif  )
}
```

If I remove the last part of the inner stream, '| remove-item -whatif', then just the names of the two files I wish to delete are presented. This means that the logic is essentially correct.

I have tried moving the '| remove-item' part to other places in the syntax (for instance to after the final closing } ), and the result is the same: it will delete the files I want to delete and present the aforementioned error for the rest.

I either want to have a syntax that doesn't error, or that suppresses this error, avoiding distractions when the command is run.

OS is Windows 10, PS Version 5.1

Regards,
Nigel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nigel,

Give this syntax a go, it worked for me.

```
(gci -Path "G:\Test\Scripts\*Dev*V*.ps1" -file).FullName  |
  Where-object {((Get-Content $_ | measure-object -line).lines) -gt 20
         } | Remove-Item
```

Of course, change the path selection info and the test and test value to your needs. You many also need to add the -Force parameter to the Remove-Item just in case some of the files are marked read-only.

---

Comment: Thank you, this worked a charm.  The fact that your sample went direct to the Where-Object without needing to use the ForEach-Object (%) confirms my hunch that it was the loop clause which was causing my issue.

I also like the first part of your sample, (gci ...).FullName, as this neatly gets just that part of the information that I need right away.  Since I only plan to run this command in the actual folder where the files reside, (gci.. ).Name works just as well for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Remove-Item cmdlet expects to bind its property "Path" by either PropertyName or Value.  This means that the object you pass in must either be an object that has a Path property or a string that is the full path to the file.

You'll want to replace the property 'Name' with 'FullName'

Here is the help for the Path parameter on Remove-Item

```
Get-Help Remove-Item -Parameter Path

  -Path <System.String[]>
        Specifies a path of the items being removed. Wildcard characters are permitted.

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    0
        Default value                None
        Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName, ByValue)
        Accept wildcard characters?  true
```

Comment: Ditto to what `Daniel` says here, but also of note. Never, ever run destructive `(Add/Create/New, Remove/Delete/Modify/Update/Rename)` code until you validate what it is doing first, you could seriously damage your host/enterprise operations/data. Master -WhatIf/Confirm as well as `Trace-Command` to see the call stack of the operation and `Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer`, to ensure your code is folowing a set of rules.